# Which js files are required to implement jqGrid witrh subgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to implement subgrid in jqGrid.
I added grid.subgrid.js in js lib but still in browser console I see error on console 
"Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'extend'"

```
/**
 * jqGrid extension for SubGrid Data
 * Tony Tomov tony@trirand.com
 * http://trirand.com/blog/ 
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
**/
"use strict";
**$.jgrid.extend({
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'extend'**
setSubGrid : function () {
    return this.each(function (){
        var $t = this, cm,
```

Comment: I think it depends on what features you are using.. You should have the jQuery library file and the jqGrid plugin javascript file. In then in addition to that there is a "src" folder containing javascript files for each feature.

Comment: If you can provide more code.. IE what scripts you are loading and any corresponding HTML then maybe we can help troubleshoot the error.

Comment: make sure you are including a locale.js file and loading it before the grid.js